# How to use wild card while giving file permission using Ansible?

Tags: ansible

there. I am new to ansible. I was trying to give some permission to multiple file using ansible. I aleardy tried follwoing code:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Giving file permission to tomcat/bin sh file
      file: path=/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/bin/*.sh owner=tomcat group=tomcat mode=755
```

in the above code i want to give permission to tomcat for  all .sh file located in tomcat/bin directory.I have already created a tomcat user. When i run this playbook i get this error:

```
 {"changed": false, "msg": "file (/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/bin/*.sh) is absent, cannot continue", "path": "tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/bin/*.sh", "state": "absent"}
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently gave a relevant suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50253984/ansible-how-to-give-a-command-to-all-files-in-a-directory/50256366#50256366).

```
tmp/tst: ls -ln
total 8
-r----x--- 1 521 100  16 May  9 09:40 hosts
-rwx---rwx 1 521 100 183 May  9 09:44 tst.yml

/tmp/tst: cat hosts
[tst]
localhost

/tmp/tst: cat tst.yml
---

- name: test
  hosts: tst
  tasks:
    - name: tweak permissions
      file:
        dest: "{{ item }}"
        mode: u+rw,g+r,o-w
      with_fileglob:
        - '/tmp/tst/*'

/tmp/tst: ansible-playbook -i hosts tst.yml

PLAY [test] 
********************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] 
*********************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [tweak permissions] 
*******************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/tst/hosts)
changed: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/tst/tst.yml)

PLAY RECAP 
*********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0

/tmp/tst: ls -ln
total 8
-rw-r-x--- 1 521 100  16 May  9 09:40 hosts
-rwxr--r-x 1 521 100 183 May  9 09:44 tst.yml
```

Just be careful to test it. `with_fileglob` has had issues, but `.../*.sh` might work. I'd actually recommend the methods with find/register or shell. Just adding this for options. :)

Comment: Comments never required for a downvote - but it will help people learn what's wrong with a post and not to do it if you use [http://idownvotedbecau.se](http://idownvotedbecau.se), which only takes a second if you bookmark it. Personally, I'd always like clarification, but c'est la vie.

Comment: Your suggestion works only for local machine, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55622014 for details

Comment: Good point to note. c.f. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/plugins/lookup/fileglob.html - remote systems require a more elaborated approach.

Answer (score 5):

The **file** module does not support the use of wildcards in its `path` parameter. 
You can use a combination of the **find** and **file** module as described in a blog post [here](http://www.mydailytutorials.com/ansible-delete-multiple-files-directories-ansible/):

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: Find files
    find:
      paths: /tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/bin
      patterns: "*.sh"
    register: files_to_change

  - name: Modify the file permissions
    file:
      path: "{{ item.path }}"
      owner: tomcat
      group: tomcat
      mode: 755
    with_items: "{{ files_to_change.files }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that we can use regex in the file path. But you can achieve the same using **with_items** or **shell** module . **with_items** is painful one.

```
- file :
    path : "{{ item }}"
    owner : tomcat
    group : tomcat
    mode : 755
  with_items:
    - /tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/bin/a.sh
    - /tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/bin/b.sh
```

or the **Shell** Module

```
- name: Giving file permission to tomcat/bin sh file
  shell : |
    chown tomcat:tomcat /tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/bin/*.sh
    chmod 0755 /tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/bin/*.sh
```

Answer (score -3):

After spending few days for searching for optimized answer i came with the following answer which is worked for me.

```
- file:
      path: '{{ item }}'
      owner: tomcat
      group: tomcat
      mode: 0755
    with_fileglob:
      - "/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/bin/*.sh"
```

Comment: this expands locally