# Ansible fileglob: unable to find ... in expected paths

Tags: ansible, vagrant

I am trying to use ansible to delete all of the files within a directory while keeping the directory. To that end, I'm using the `with_fileglob` key on a task to get all of the files out of that directory as `item` variables. I have created a minimum example that shows my issue here:

Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "centos/7"

  config.vm.provision :ansible do |ansible|
    ansible.limit = "all"
    ansible.playbook = "local.yml"
  end
end
```

local.yml:

```
- name: Test
  hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: Test debug
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      with_fileglob:
        - "/vagrant/*"
```

I expect to get a debug message for each file in the /vagrant directory - since this is the directory synced with the VM via Vagrant, I should get a message for the Vagrantfile, and for local.yml. Instead, I get the following confusing warning:

```
PLAY [Test] ********************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [default]

TASK [Test debug] **************************************************************
 [WARNING]: Unable to find '/vagrant' in expected paths (use -vvvvv to see
paths)


PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
default                    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

What expected paths are being referred to here? I have tried this with multiple fileglobs, and they all fail in this way, what am I missing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Ansible lookup plugins** are executed on local machine (where you launch Ansible), not remote one(s).

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html

> Lookup plugins allow Ansible to access data from outside sources. This
>   can include reading the filesystem in addition to contacting external
>   datastores and services. Like all templating, these plugins are
>   evaluated on the Ansible control machine, not on the target/remote.

Comment: @NateMara You can use [find module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html)

Answer (score 7):

Since `fileglob` only works on the local machine, I tested `find` als alternative and want to provide an example here. If we want to locate all `*.jar` files, this could be done like this:

```
- name: Find jar files
  find:
    paths: "{{ install_jar_path }}"
    patterns: "*.jar"
  register: jar_src_file
  changed_when: False
```

`jar_src_file` is now an array. Every item has a property `path`.

```
- set_fact:
    first_jar: "{{ jar_src_file.files[0].path }}"
```

This will give you the path of the first jar file for testing purpose. You could loop over the items using `with_items` for example if needed.